# windows Powershell console window is not accessible

Tags: windows, powershell

i see my powershell window is not accessible after a certain point of time,

i can see console running and available in taskmanager and taskbar, but when i click powershell console it will not launch console to desktop. i would need to launch new console instead of existing one.
used to exit older console from task manager - "End Task"

Windows + Tab also will not help to get console back to desktop. its really annoying most time.

OS - Windows 10

PS version = 5.1.14393.2312

Comment: Is this a VM or a standalone machine? Is this a standard WIn10 install or on an insiders build (Fast or skip ahead)? The reason for the query, is that I've seen this happen, but only on VM I am RDP'd in to and only on the insiders build. No fix that I am aware of to date. I've also seen this happen in the same scenario for other apps, Explorer, task Manager, etc. Lastly, what PS version (RTM on insiders build) are you using, default PS or PSCore or both?

Comment: i see issue in both standalone and RDP of other standalone system. I did not see this issue happening for other apps. how ever i notice recently i stared importing new module UIAwrapper.dll in the powershell. i believe i started seeing issues after that.

Comment: If it were me. I'd pull that from a few systems and validate again.

Comment: How about using win + R  to run the powershell.

Comment: im pretty sure this is due to the module i imported,  today my colleague also faced similar issue after he started importing uiautomation module into his console.

Answer (score -2):

This is all I can think of---

[PowerShell Properties picture, click to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr0zz.jpg)

Open PowerShell Properties.
Set it to open in a Normal Window.

Comment: Although I would say that this belongs in a comment as it is a only a remotely related suggestion without even an explanation of why it may fix the issue or why the issue is occurring (and which will most likely not work). Answers should actually be tested and known to be working, or at the very least be supported by plausible reasoning. Pure speculation belongs in a comment (if that).